# GPU Drives issue with Ubuntu 22.04, External monitors freeze

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

i am currently having an issue that if I were to connect my laptop to a external monitors, the external monitors completely freezes. I can still move the cursor and the monitor on my laptop works fine but it is still pretty annoying and i have to turn off and on my laptop for this to fix it self, unplugging and plugging it back it does not work.

My laptop is a lenovo legion pro 7
4070 gpu and i9 13th gen I believe
I have two external monitors, one plugged in via HDMI and one via USB -C

To be honest i am not 100% sure if this is a drivers issue, i have gone to the software and update app to change drivers for the graphics card and issue still persists

I have reinstalled ubuntu twice and once completely erased the partition to do a full restart (i am dual booting and i have 0 issues on the Windows 11 end)

the only reason i use ubuntu is for software development and having a 2nd and 3rd monitor is kind of important to me, so you can imagine that the only things i have installed are VSC and Spotify basically.

These freezes occur at any instance and this is a list of times it has happened so far:

- run a local server using npm start (website with phaser instance
  running)
- run a rust program with cargo run (i was running the bevy game
  engine)
- opening up a visual studio window after it has been minimized
- changing video on youtube (i don't remember if this is when i tried
  to maximize the video window)

I cant really see a pattern to be honest in what could cause this issue. Maybe the fact that all 4 instance is where the GPU sort of gets utilised lead me to believe is a GPU driver issue...

There was a period where this didn't happen and then since the 19th of October 2023 i did a system update and it started doing it again. I have since reinstalled ubuntu but the issue persists.

I tried to give as much info as I could, if there is something that I missed or its needed pls ask, I would love to use my second monitor. Coding with only one monitor is a pain in the ass :)

Thanks in advance, I really do appreciate it.